# Returning a field which is not in the model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `projects` which store `batches` of records. When retrieving a `project` from my mongoDB using mongoose, I want to calculate the number of batches which belong to that specific project.

My Project model-schema currently looks like so:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

My batch model-schema looks:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  project:{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project',
    required: true
  },
  file: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  orginal_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

I have a function which counts the number of batches that belong to a project based off of the `batch.project` field and then adds to it to the JSON object of the project (e.g `project.batchCount`). However I have run into a problem where the new field `project.batchCount` is being removed by the by the models toJSON or toObject function because the field is not present in the model-schema.

My current solution is to add it to the model-schema as a 'dummy field' which is never saved to the mongoDB:

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  batchCount: {
    type: Number
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

However I do not like this way as it makes my model larger than it needs to be and slightly less 'readable'.

Is there a better way to do this? And if so how?

Comment: Try adding batchCount after calling toObject.

Comment: As `toObject` converts mongo document to plain javascript object thus try to add `batchCount` after using `toObject`.

Comment: @FarhanTahir I thought of this but I would like to make use of a mongoose model-static function to calculate the count. When you call toObject you lose the static functions if I understand the function correctly.

Comment: static functions does not have effect over object.  you don not use static function with object, either you use static function with Model like Model.methodName. so I don't think you'll lose static functions.

Comment: Create a static function and get count from there, then using toObject get plian JS object then simply add `project.batchCount  = countfromstaticfunction`

Comment: Why we should do this way is you are not using batchCount for saving in mongodb you just wanna use it on front-end may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a virtual on the schema. A virtual on a document in mongoose is available locally, but doesn't get saved to the DB.

I liked the idea of using a static on the schema to get the project counts. I also liked the idea of just calling the method on the document rather than the Model, so I implemented it in an instance method. A static would have worked just as well. It depends on your preference.

Here is what I came up with:

**batch.js**

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const batchSchema = new Schema({
  project: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Project',
    required: true
  },
  file: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  original_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

batchSchema.virtual('projectCount')
  .get(function () {
    return this._projectCount;
  })
  .set(function (v) {
    this._projectCount = v;
  });

batchSchema.methods.count = async function () {
  let found = await this.model('Batch').count({ project: this.project });
  this._projectCount = found;
};


const Batch = mongoose.model('Batch', batchSchema);

module.exports = Batch;
```

The virtual called projectCount has a simple setter and getter to overwrite the value if you need to or retrieve it once it's been set.

The instance method on each document is called count() and calls the Model.count() method with a query for the current document's project _id.

**project.js**

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const projectSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);

module.exports = Project;
```

**populate.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
const conn = mongoose.connection;
const Batch = require('./batch');
const Project = require('./project');

const projects = [];
const batches = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const project = new Project({
    name: `project${i}`,
    slug: `slug${i}`
  });
  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    const batch = new Batch({
      project: project._id,
      file: `file${j}`,
      original_name: `name${j}`
    });
    batches.push(batch);
  }
  projects.push(project);
}

async function add () {
  await conn.dropDatabase();
  const savedProjects = await Project.create(projects);
  const savedBatches = await Batch.create(batches);
  console.log(`Added ${savedProjects.length} projects.`);
  console.log(`Added ${savedBatches.length} batches.`);
  return conn.close();
}

add();
```

populate.js is just how I created the collections and the docs for this example, nothing fancy here.

**get.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
const conn = mongoose.connection;
const Batch = require('./batch');

async function get () {
  let f = await Batch.findOne({});
  await f.count();
  console.log(`the project for this batch has ${f.projectCount} matches`);
  return conn.close();
}

get().catch(console.error);
```

Once the instance method count() is called, we have access to the value stored in the virtual `projectCount`.

**bash output**

```
49729301: ./populate.js
Added 10 projects.
Added 100 batches.
49729301: ./get.js
the project for this batch has 10 matches
49729301:
```

**mongo shell output**

```
49729301: mongo --quiet test
> db.batches.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5acbbebb4cd320cb4e403e8f"),
        "project" : ObjectId("5acbbebb4cd320cb4e403e8e"),
        "file" : "file0",
        "original_name" : "name0",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T19:27:55.395Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-04-09T19:27:55.395Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
>
```

as you can see, virtual properties are only available locally, and do not get stored in the db.

Comment: This is perfect. However I just want to add that after some research, ignorer to make this work, you must add `toObject: { virtuals: true }` to your schema settings.

Comment: Sorry, as well as `toObject: { virtuals: true }`. That way the field should always be present